# jquery: animation must go on (animation and sync ajax request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation, wait

all!

I use the following code:
1) activate animations. eg:

```
$( ". Wait-screen"). FadeTo (250, 1.0);
```

2) sending a request to the server and waiting for a reply:

```
$.ajax(async: false, ...);
```

When begins to execute a request to the server all the stops - the animation is not running, but as soon as the request is completed - all runs

How to make so that during **synchronous request** (async: false) animation in the browser worked?

Comment: You cannot and anyway there is absolutely no reason to send synchronous ajax request... You have to learn how to use asynchronous request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous means only one line of code can run at a time. So the request your making will block all other code until it is finished. You're going to have to set `async: true` for it to be non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous means that the code is blocking: all the rest of your js code will be halt until the request returns. So, the animation being blocked is the **intended expected result**, since no javascript is messing with the DOM until the request returns. Maybe, sometimes, there is a good reason to make a synchronous ajax request -but I never did-, but in this case, when you have an animation going on, doesn't seem this is one of those cases.

Is there a special reason to make the request synchronous?

If, for some specific reason, you absolutely need the request to be synchronous, maybe -and I don't know, I never tested that-, using a pure css animation will work.

Comment: I need

1) to show the user a relaxing animation :)

2) perform a query annoyingly long (a few seconds)

3) disable animations

4) to continue processing the data

Use .done () structure is very inconvenient (perhaps even eliminated) because the request code and the code of the subsequent work in different locations of html code